# how to work with dynamics and animated objecs

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I want to drop several objects into a jar one by one, not all at the same time. How can I achieve this? I tried to hold objects with another passive rigid body and then animate that object away allowing objects to fall, but the active rigid body objects dont animate at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to blender myself, but I think your solution would lie in the timeline key frames. For each object you can start movement at one key frame, move, and stop at another key frame. Hope this helps.